# Gradle: set java virtual machine (jvm) stack size for task run? (eg. pass -Xss80m to jvm)

Tags: java, gradle

When I use Gradle to execute my Java program, I'd like to manually set the stack size. Executing java from command line, it would be something like `java -Xss80m`, but I'm new to Gradle and struggling a bit to find the best or standard way to do this with a build script...

Excerpt of my Gradle build script is below:

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   main = 'loadBuybackRowsIntoSQL'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html), `jvmArgs` is what you need:

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
    ...
    jvmArgs '-Xss80m' // will add this argument to list
    // or
    jvmArgs = ['-Xss80m'] // will replace arguments list
}
```